Why does the turtle not move in a square?
How do I move this, and make a square a proper position.
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(2)

    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()

At the moment it does this:


Your question is extremely unclear - what does "make a square a proper position" mean?  To draw a square, you're going to have to move the turtle at least four times, rather than just once.

draw_square is a bad place to create your window.

I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but if you want to draw a square instead of just a line, then you have to use a for loop to repeat the drawing part four times. (If your question was something different, please edit it to make it clearer.)
Also, there is no need to call your turtle "brad"; t is conventional, although you can call it brad if you want :)
import turtle


def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.shape("turtle")
    t.color("yellow")
    t.speed(2)

    for i in range(4):  # <---
        t.forward(100)
        t.right(90)

    window.exitonclick()


draw_square()

Output (zoomed in):

I hope this helps.

Let them call their turtle however they want... :-)

yertle would be an unconventional but appropriate variable name.

@Chris is it better now?

To paraphrase CS Lewis, the naming of turtles is a difficult matter.

you must adjust your code like that to draw the square
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(2)

    brad.penup()  
    brad.goto(-50, 50)  
    brad.pendown() 

    for _ in range(4):
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()


try this, it works for me

I'd guess the lack of indentation in your first version of the answer attracted the downvote.

oh probably :) i should take care of that
